# How to run a function asyncronous?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I have an `array`

```
coords = [];
```

Then I run this function

```
    getVirusData();

    function getVirusData() {
      getAvailableDatasets()
      .then(combineDatasets)
      .then(data => { // It's asynchronous
        coords.push.apply(coords, data.map(item => item.Lat +"," + item.Long));
      });
    }

    function getAvailableDatasets() {
      return $.getJSON('https://api.github.com/repos/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/contents/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series')
        .then((files) => {
          return Promise.all(
            files.filter(file => /^time_series_19-covid-.+\.csv$/.test(file.name))
            .map(file => getDataset(file.download_url))
          );
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
          console.log(err);
        })
    }

    function getDataset(url) {
      return $.ajax(url)
        .then(csv => {
          const output = Papa.parse(csv, {
            header: true, // Convert rows to Objects using headers as properties
            dynamicTyping: true, // Convert some fields to Numbers automatically
          });
          if (output.data) {
            const labelMatches = url.match(/time_series_19-covid-(.+)\.csv$/);
            const label = labelMatches ? labelMatches[1] : "Untitled";

            const formatted = output.data.map(area => {
              const obj = {};

              Object.keys(area).forEach(key => {
                if (/^\d+\/\d+\/\d+$/.test(key)) {
                  obj[key] = { date: key, [label]: area[key] };
                } else {
                  obj[key] = area[key];
                }
              });

              return obj;
            });



            return formatted;
          } else {
            console.log(output.errors);
          }
        });
    }

    function combineDatasets(datasets) {
      if (datasets.length) {
        const combined = datasets.reduce((result, dataset, i) => {
          if (i === 0) { return result; }
          dataset.forEach(area => {
            // Look for area with same coordinates
            let existingArea = result.find(a => a.Lat === area.Lat && a.Long === area.Long);
            if (!existingArea) {
              result.push(area);
            } else {
              const dates = Object.keys(area).filter(key => /^\d+\/\d+\/\d+$/.test(key));
              dates.forEach(date => existingArea[date] = Object.assign(area[date], existingArea[date]));
            }
          });
          return result;
        }, datasets[0]);

        return combined.map(area => {
          const obj = { data: [] };

          Object.keys(area).forEach(key => {
            if (/^\d+\/\d+\/\d+$/.test(key)) {
              obj.data.push(area[key]);
            } else {
              obj[key] = area[key];
            }
          });

          return obj;
        });
      } else {
        throw "No datasets were found";
      }
    }
```

Then after I have pushed all the values into the array, I need to run this

```
    drawMarkers();

    function drawMarkers() {
      for (var a = 0; a < coords.length; ++a) {
          var pin = coords[a].split(',');
          var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(pin[0], pin[1]);
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latLng
          });
       }
      }
```

At the moment as I run `drawMarkers();` I get no markers and if I `console.log(pin)` after the `for loop` I get nothing, therefore there must be an `asynchronous` issue

**UPDATE FULL CODE**

```
      (function($) {

        var markers = [],
          circle,
          latitude = [],
          longitude = [],
          datesExternal = [],
          links = [],
          years = [],
          type = [],
          coords = [],
          oggetti = [],
          scuole = [],
          privati = [],
          markerCluster,
          ids = [],
          currentSite = [],
          author = [],
          site = [],
          titles = [];

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: 40.600486, lng: 9.261252},
          zoomControl: true,
          zoom: 2,
          minZoom: 2,
          maxZoom: 18,
          noClear: true,
          zoomControlOptions: {
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_CENTER
          },
          styles: [
                    {
                        "featureType": "administrative",
                        "elementType": "all",
                        "stylers": [
                            {
                                "visibility": "simplified"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "featureType": "administrative",
                        "elementType": "geometry.fill",
                        "stylers": [
                            {
                                "visibility": "off"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "featureType": "administrative",
                        "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
                        "stylers": [
                            {
                                "weight": "1.00"
                            },
                            {
                                "color": "#ffffff"
                            },
                            {
                                "visibility": "off"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "featureType": "administrative",
                        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
                        "stylers": [
                            {
                                "color": "#484848"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "featureType": "administrative.country",
                        "elementType": "all",
                        "stylers": [
                            {
                                "visibility": "simplified"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "featureType": "administrative.country",
                        "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
                        "stylers": [
                            {
                                "visibility": "on"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "featureType": "administrative.country",
                        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
                        "stylers": [
                            {
                                "color": "#484848"
                            },
                            {
                                "visibility": "simplified"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "featureType": "administrative.province",
                        "elementType": "all",
                        "stylers": [
                            {
                                "visibility": "simplified"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "featureType": "administrative.province",
                        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
                        "stylers": [
                            {
                                "color": "#484848"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "featureType": "administrative.locality",
                        "elementType": "all",
                        "stylers": [
                            {
                                "visibility": "simplified"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "featureType": "administrative.neighborhood",
                        "elementType": "all",
                        "stylers": [
                            {
                                "visibility": "off"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "featureType": "administrative.neighborhood",
                        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
                        "stylers": [
                            {
                                "visibility": "simplified"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "featureType": "administrative.land_parcel",
                        "elementType": "all",
                        "stylers": [
                            {
                                "visibility": "off"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "featureType": "landscape",
                        "elementType": "all",
                        "stylers": [
                            {
                                "color": "#e2e2e2"
                            },
                            {
                                "visibility": "simplified"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "featureType": "landscape",
                        "elementType": "labels",
                        "stylers": [
                            {
                                "color": "#484848"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "featureType": "landscape.natural",
                        "elementType": "all",
                        "stylers": [
                            {
                                "visibility": "simplified"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "featureType": "landscape.natural",
                        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
                        "stylers": [
                            {
                                "color": "#484848"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "featureType": "poi",
                        "elementType": "all",
                        "stylers": [
                            {
                                "visibility": "off"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "featureType": "road",
                        "elementType": "all",
                        "stylers": [
                            {
                                "visibility": "off"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "featureType": "road.local",
                        "elementType": "all",
                        "stylers": [
                            {
                                "visibility": "simplified"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "featureType": "transit",
                        "elementType": "all",
                        "stylers": [
                            {
                                "visibility": "off"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "featureType": "water",
                        "elementType": "all",
                        "stylers": [
                            {
                                "color": "#ededed"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
          draggable: true,
          clickable: true,
          streetViewControl: false,
          rotateControl: false,
          fullscreenControl: false,
          scrollwheel: false,
          animatedZoom: false,
          navigationControl: false,
          mapTypeControl: false,
          scaleControl: false
        });


getVirusData();

function getVirusData() {
  getAvailableDatasets()
    .then(combineDatasets)
    .then(data => { // It's asynchronous
      coords.push.apply(coords, data.map(item => item.Lat + "," + item.Long));
    }).then(function(entry) {
      for (var a = 0; a < coords.length; a++) {
        var pin = coords[a].split(',');
        console.log(pin);
        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(pin[0], pin[1]);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: latLng
        });
      }
    });
}

function getAvailableDatasets() {
  return $.getJSON('https://api.github.com/repos/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/contents/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series')
    .then((files) => {
      return Promise.all(
        files.filter(file => /^time_series_19-covid-.+\.csv$/.test(file.name))
        .map(file => getDataset(file.download_url))
      );
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    })
}

function getDataset(url) {
  return $.ajax(url)
    .then(csv => {
      const output = Papa.parse(csv, {
        header: true, // Convert rows to Objects using headers as properties
        dynamicTyping: true, // Convert some fields to Numbers automatically
      });
      if (output.data) {
        const labelMatches = url.match(/time_series_19-covid-(.+)\.csv$/);
        const label = labelMatches ? labelMatches[1] : "Untitled";

        const formatted = output.data.map(area => {
          const obj = {};

          Object.keys(area).forEach(key => {
            if (/^\d+\/\d+\/\d+$/.test(key)) {
              obj[key] = {
                date: key,
                [label]: area[key]
              };
            } else {
              obj[key] = area[key];
            }
          });

          return obj;
        });



        return formatted;
      } else {
        console.log(output.errors);
      }
    });
}

function combineDatasets(datasets) {
  if (datasets.length) {
    const combined = datasets.reduce((result, dataset, i) => {
      if (i === 0) {
        return result;
      }
      dataset.forEach(area => {
        // Look for area with same coordinates
        let existingArea = result.find(a => a.Lat === area.Lat && a.Long === area.Long);
        if (!existingArea) {
          result.push(area);
        } else {
          const dates = Object.keys(area).filter(key => /^\d+\/\d+\/\d+$/.test(key));
          dates.forEach(date => existingArea[date] = Object.assign(area[date], existingArea[date]));
        }
      });
      return result;
    }, datasets[0]);

    return combined.map(area => {
      const obj = {
        data: []
      };

      Object.keys(area).forEach(key => {
        if (/^\d+\/\d+\/\d+$/.test(key)) {
          obj.data.push(area[key]);
        } else {
          obj[key] = area[key];
        }
      });

      return obj;
    });
  } else {
    throw "No datasets were found";
  }
}
```

Comment: Where are you placing your call to ``drawMarkers()``? It should go immediately after ``coords.push.apply(...)``.

Comment: I have just placed it there but it stops after 1. Also tried this way but I get the same result https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60584532/how-to-loop-after-then

Comment: Please show your complete code exactly as you have tested it.

Comment: @kmoser come to chat?

Comment: @rob.m check the console in my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably, the script you are referring to is incorrect. Check the console by running the script below. Also shifted your `drawMarker` logic to the very end of the calls.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
```

```js
let coords = [];

getVirusData();

function getVirusData() {
  getAvailableDatasets()
    .then(combineDatasets)
    .then(data => { // It's asynchronous
      coords.push.apply(coords, data.map(item => item.Lat + "," + item.Long));
    }).then(function(entry) {
      for (var a = 0; a < coords.length; a++) {
        var pin = coords[a].split(',');
        console.log(pin);
        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(pin[0], pin[1]);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: latLng
        });
      }
    });
}

function getAvailableDatasets() {
  return $.getJSON('https://api.github.com/repos/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/contents/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series')
    .then((files) => {
      return Promise.all(
        files.filter(file => /^time_series_19-covid-.+\.csv$/.test(file.name))
        .map(file => getDataset(file.download_url))
      );
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    })
}

function getDataset(url) {
  return $.ajax(url)
    .then(csv => {
      const output = Papa.parse(csv, {
        header: true, // Convert rows to Objects using headers as properties
        dynamicTyping: true, // Convert some fields to Numbers automatically
      });
      if (output.data) {
        const labelMatches = url.match(/time_series_19-covid-(.+)\.csv$/);
        const label = labelMatches ? labelMatches[1] : "Untitled";

        const formatted = output.data.map(area => {
          const obj = {};

          Object.keys(area).forEach(key => {
            if (/^\d+\/\d+\/\d+$/.test(key)) {
              obj[key] = {
                date: key,
                [label]: area[key]
              };
            } else {
              obj[key] = area[key];
            }
          });

          return obj;
        });



        return formatted;
      } else {
        console.log(output.errors);
      }
    });
}

function combineDatasets(datasets) {
  if (datasets.length) {
    const combined = datasets.reduce((result, dataset, i) => {
      if (i === 0) {
        return result;
      }
      dataset.forEach(area => {
        // Look for area with same coordinates
        let existingArea = result.find(a => a.Lat === area.Lat && a.Long === area.Long);
        if (!existingArea) {
          result.push(area);
        } else {
          const dates = Object.keys(area).filter(key => /^\d+\/\d+\/\d+$/.test(key));
          dates.forEach(date => existingArea[date] = Object.assign(area[date], existingArea[date]));
        }
      });
      return result;
    }, datasets[0]);

    return combined.map(area => {
      const obj = {
        data: []
      };

      Object.keys(area).forEach(key => {
        if (/^\d+\/\d+\/\d+$/.test(key)) {
          obj.data.push(area[key]);
        } else {
          obj[key] = area[key];
        }
      });

      return obj;
    });
  } else {
    throw "No datasets were found";
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/papaparse@5.1.1/papaparse.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
```

Comment: why pins are not placed tho?

Comment: @rob.m you don't have any code in the html to point to the specific id. Maybe create a separate thread for that

Comment: updated the question with full map code but no pins are placed

Comment: @rob.m thats because you are using new instances for markers, use the same map variable that you have used to initialize.

Comment: sorry mate i'm getting confused where?

Comment: i don't understand where I should be using the map var

Comment: got it! ,
    map: map,

Answer (score 0):

You could return the promise from `getVirusData()` and return the new coords.

```
function getVirusData() {
  return getAvailableDatasets()
  .then(combineDatasets)
  .then(data => { // It's asynchronous
    coords.push.apply(coords, data.map(item => item.Lat +"," + item.Long));
    return coords;
  });
}
```

This way you can pass the coords directly into `drawMarkers()` like:

```
function drawMarkers(coordinates) {
  for (var a = 0; a < coordinates.length; ++a) {
    var pin = coordinates[a].split(',');
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(pin[0], pin[1]);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: latLng
    });
  }
}
```

And to pass it asynchronously, you would use `.then` on `getVirusData()`

```
getVirusData()
.then(coordinates => {
  drawMarkers(coordinates);
});
```

Comment: ok i tried but then If I do               var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latLng
              });
     console.log(pin)  I only get one object from the array and markers are not set

Comment: How many objects are supposed to be in the array? Are they there before the for loop? I.e. what is the value of `coordinates`?

Comment: coords has plenty of values, but if I do console.log(coordinates); before function drawMarkers(coordinates) { i get an error as not defined

Comment: Then your problem isn't with asynchronous functions. My answer is a common way to do this asynchronously, and you should still be doing that